# Add "checked" to input when parent "a" selected, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<a onclick='addSelector(this)'>
    <img src='resources/img/produkti/test.jpg'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='test.jpg' name='main_image'>
</a>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function addSelector(elem) {
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
   for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       a[i].classList.remove('selected')
   }
   elem.classList.add('selected');
   elem.find( 'input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
   }
```

So, when 'a' is clicked, it gets 'selected' class. I want to make it so child input gets 'checked' too. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That is bad design having a checkbox inside of a link. I am not sure if that is even valid HTML. Why are you not using labels? And you are reinventing radio buttons?

Comment: is you elem a jQuery object ? and if so which DOM element is, I also second what epascarello said

Comment: did you try using navigating to child elements

Comment: The console should have the error *"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"*

Comment: Ok. This is the only way, i figured that I could pass that selected input element to controller. So there must be a better way,then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the anchor (which isn't being used as an anchor anyway) with a `<label>`.

This will have the behaviour you want by default. It will also associate the alt text (which you should add) of the image with the input for screen readers.

Comment: Something like this?      <a><label for='test'><img><input id='test'>text</label></a>

Comment: Just remove the anchors entirely: `<label for='test'><img /><input id='test' />text</label>`

Answer (score 2):

epascarello's comment is correct, but ultimately your problem is that `elem` is not a jQuery object. You might have better success with `$(elem)` on your last line (or wherever you are applying jQuery functions).

A much better way of writing the whole thing would be to have a click listener on the element instead like this:

```
// Listen for an anchor being clicked
$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    // Remove selected class from all anchors
    $('a').removeClass('selected');

    // Add selected class to this element
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // Make the relevant checkbox ticked
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);

});
```

Although as mentioned on here elsewhere, a label is better than an anchor :).

Comment: Thank you, I did this with label and radio button! Works great! Thank you!